# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error while attempt to browse web application

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

On my attempt to access my site from IIS, i am getting following error.

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Module: IIS Web Core
Notification: Unknown
Handler: Not yet determinedError Code
Error Code: 0x80070005
Config Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
Logon Method:Not yet determined
Logon User:Not yet determined

I am not sure what to do. I have already given full control to mycomputerName\ISS_IUSRS for applicationHost file in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config. Also, I have given  full control to mycomputerName\ISS_IUSRS for applicationHost file to my solution folder and web.config file. However, when I click on my application from IIS and attempt to browse it by clicking on manage Application\browse, I am still getting this error.

If anyone could help me, that would greatly be appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This problem mostly occurs when the IIS application don't have the permission to the read the application configuration files. IIS application uses the **IIS_IUSRS** user to read the Web application.

The IIS_IUSRS user will have default read and execute access for the folder C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ once when you install the IIS. Kindly copy your Web Application folder to the above mentioned directory and give the read access or full control(if the IIS_IUSRS don't have the read and execute permission) for the IIS_IUSRS to your application folder.